# Does SubGit require an own GIT installation

Tags: git, svn, repository, subgit

The question is very simple:

I have an external SVN-Repository (foreign network) and I want to establish for my local network a GIT-environment. As SubGit can synchronize this SVN with the to-be-done GIT-Server, I need to know if I need to install an own GIT-Server or does SubGit "include" a GIT-Server-Installation?

So is Subgit just a "converter" like: SVN<->SUBGIT<->GIT (master repo)
or
is SubGit also a GIT-Server like: SVN<->SUBGIT (=master repo) (no extra git required)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SubGit doesn't include Git server, you should install the server on your own. Note, that SubGit uses 'pre-receive' and 'post-receive' Git hooks, so you should use a server that runs these hooks when someone pushes commits to the server (nearly all servers do that, except Gerrit --- there's an [issue](http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SGT-632) for that). For example you can use Atlassian [Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash) server and SubGit [plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.tmatesoft.subgit.stash-svn-importer) for it.

So SubGit is rather SVN<->SUBGIT (=master repo), you need no extra Git repository on your server. Just set up the access to that repository from your local network.

Comment: Hi, I am a bit confused; you say "SubGit doesn't include Git server, you should install the server on your own" and on the other hand "So SubGit is rather SVN<->SUBGIT (=master repo), you need no extra Git repository on your server". Do I need to install Git Server or not? A Git repo without a Server makes no sense i think

Comment: I have one Server, where Id like to install SubGit and the repo to synchornize. The question is if i also have to install GIT (or does SubGit include Git?)

Comment: The answer depends on details, you may contact me (the e-mail is in my profile). In short: in some cases Git without a Server makes sense (by "server" I mean software that serves some TCP port). You have to install Git and configure any of Git servers to serve the repository unless you're are the only developer. SubGit doesn't include Git, it just adds synchronization ability to a Git server.